# Vue Lifecycle Hook getting called twice

Tags: laravel, vue.js, lifecycle

Why is it that when I'm running a Laravel Application (php artisan serve) and Vue (npm run dev) together, my Vuejs Lifecycle hooks get called twice. But when Vue.js is standalone (Vue-Cli) that does not occur. Is there a way of stopping that from happing when your application is a combination of Laravel + Vue together?

Codes Below:

Dashboard.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <NavBar />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-12 mx-auto">
            <hr class="separator" />
            <h6 class="text-success" align="center">
              <b>Today's Feedback Statistics</b>
            </h6>
            <hr class="separator" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <!--Beginning of today's data -->
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
            <router-link
              class="text-decoration-none text-dark"
              :to="{ name: 'TodaysRecords'}"
            >
              <div
                class="card bg-white mb-4 shadow-sm"
                style="
                  width: 14rem;
                  border-radius: 0.5em;
                  border-bottom: 4px solid #50c878;
                "
              >
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="card-title"><span v-html="total_today"></span></h1>
                  <hr class="separator" />
                  <p class="card-text">
                    <b class="font-pref14">TOTAL FEEDBACK RECEIVED</b>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </router-link>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
            <router-link
              class="text-decoration-none text-dark"
              :to="{ name: 'TodaysRecordsAccreditedUsers'}"
            >
              <div
                class="card bg-white mb-4 shadow-sm"
                style="
                  width: 14rem;
                  border-radius: 0.5em;
                  border-bottom: 4px solid #afe1af;
                "
              >
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="card-title">
                    <span v-html="total_today_accredited"></span>
                  </h1>
                  <hr class="separator" />
                  <p class="card-text">
                    <b class="font-pref14">FROM ACCREDITED USERS</b>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </router-link>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
            <router-link
              class="text-decoration-none text-dark"
              :to="{ name: 'TodaysRecordsPublicUsers'}"
            >
              <div
                class="card bg-white mb-4 shadow-sm"
                style="
                  width: 14rem;
                  border-radius: 0.5em;
                  border-bottom: 4px solid #00a36c;
                "
              >
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="card-title">
                    <span v-html="total_today_public"></span>
                  </h1>
                  <hr class="separator" />
                  <p class="card-text">
                    <b class="font-pref14">FROM PUBLIC USERS</b>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </router-link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--End of today's data-->
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="row">
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-12 mx-auto">
            <hr class="separator" />
            <h6 class="text-success" align="center">
              <b>Absolute Feedback Statistics</b>
            </h6>
            <hr class="separator" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <!--Beginning of absolute data -->
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
            <router-link
              class="text-decoration-none text-dark"
              :to="{ name: 'AbsoluteRecords'}"
            >
              <div
                class="card bg-white mb-4 shadow-sm"
                style="
                  width: 14rem;
                  border-radius: 0.5em;
                  border-bottom: 4px solid #93c572;
                "
              >
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="card-title">
                    <span v-html="total_absolute"></span>
                  </h1>
                  <hr class="separator" />
                  <p class="card-text">
                    <b class="font-pref14">TOTAL FEEDBACK RECEIVED</b>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </router-link>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
            <router-link
              class="text-decoration-none text-dark"
              :to="{ name: 'AbsoluteRecordsAccreditedUsers'}"
            >
              <div
                class="card bg-white mb-4 shadow-sm"
                style="
                  width: 14rem;
                  border-radius: 0.5em;
                  border-bottom: 4px solid #e39802;
                "
              >
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="card-title">
                    <span v-html="total_absolute_accredited"></span>
                  </h1>
                  <hr class="separator" />
                  <p class="card-text">
                    <b class="font-pref14">FROM ACCREDITED USERS</b>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </router-link>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
            <router-link
              class="text-decoration-none text-dark"
              :to="{ name: 'AbsoluteRecordsPublicUsers'}"
            >
              <div
                class="card bg-white mb-4 shadow-sm"
                style="
                  width: 14rem;
                  border-radius: 0.5em;
                  border-bottom: 4px solid #b60a1c;
                "
              >
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="card-title">
                    <span v-html="total_absolute_public"></span>
                  </h1>
                  <hr class="separator" />
                  <p class="card-text">
                    <b class="font-pref14">FROM PUBLIC USERS</b>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </router-link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--End of today's data-->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import http from "./../http-common.js";
import NavBar from './navigations/DashboardNav.vue';
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    beforeCreate: function () {
        if (!this.$session.exists()) {
            this.$router.push('/admin');
        }
        else{
            if(this.$session.get("role") != "Admin"){
                alert("You do not have privilege to visit this page.");
                this.$session.destroy();
                this.$router.push('/admin');
            }
        }
    },
    data() {
        return{
            total_today: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw text-secondary"></i>',
            total_today_accredited: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw text-secondary"></i>',
            total_today_public: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw text-secondary"></i>',
            total_absolute: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw text-secondary"></i>',
            total_absolute_accredited: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw text-secondary"></i>',
            total_absolute_public: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw text-secondary"></i>'
        }
    },
    components:{
        NavBar
    },
    created(){
        //Beginning of today's total
        http.get("/total-today")
        .then(response =>{
            this.total_today = '<b style="color: #50c878">'+ response.data +'</b>';
        })
        .catch();

        http.get("/total-accredited-today")
        .then(response =>{
            this.total_today_accredited = '<b style="color: #AFE1AF">'+ response.data +'</b>';
        })
        .catch();

        http.get("/total-public-today")
        .then(response =>{
            this.total_today_public = '<b style="color: #00A36C">'+ response.data +'</b>';
        })
        .catch();

        //Begining of absolute total
        http.get("/total")
        .then(response =>{
            this.total_absolute = '<b style="color: #93C572">'+ response.data +'</b>';
        })
        .catch();

        http.get("/total-accredited")
        .then(response =>{
            this.total_absolute_accredited = '<b style="color: #E39802">'+ response.data +'</b>';
        })
        .catch();

        http.get("/total-public")
        .then(response =>{
            this.total_absolute_public = '<b style="color: #B60A1C">'+ response.data +'</b>';
        })
        .catch();

    }
}
</script>
```

app.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './components/App.vue';
import routes from './router';
import VueSession from 'vue-session';
Vue.use(VueSession);

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const app = new Vue({
  router: routes,
  render: h => h(App),
  el: '#app'
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  setup() { /* */ },
}
</script>
```

survey.blade.php

```php
@extends('template')
@section('title', 'Customer Satisfaction Survey')
@section('content')

<Survey></Survey>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

and Finally,
template.blade.php

```php
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ URL::asset('images/cac_icon.ico') }}" >
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

            <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }} - @yield('title')</title>

            <!-- Fonts -->
            
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <!-- Scripts -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/survey-css.css') }}">
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css"> -->
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
            <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/v-tooltip@2.1.3/dist/v-tooltip.min.js"></script>
            

            <style>
                .body{
                    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden" >
                <div class="container-bg">
                    <div class="fcta-header">
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/cac-logo.png') }}" class = "img-responsive" height="100%" />
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/coat-of-arms.png') }}" align="right" class = "img-responsive" height="100%" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="app" style="margin-top: 0px">
                            @yield('content')
                    </div>
                    

                    <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer class="page-footer font-small fixed-bottom font-small" >
                        <!-- Copyright -->
                        <div class="footer-copyright text-center text-white py-5 font-pref14">
                            © 2022 Copyright - Corporate Affairs Commission: ICT Department
                        </div>
                        <!-- Copyright -->
                    </footer>
                    <!-- Footer -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you share some code? And which specific hooks are called twice, `mounted`?

Comment: @Lissy93 I've updated my post with the relevant codes. created, mounted and even beforeCreated are called twice. When i'm routed to a page, the calls are made just once. But once I refresh the browser, they get called twice.

Comment: You're loading `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>` twice, aren't you?

Comment: ABSOLUTELY RIGHT!!! Thank you so much @Lissy93. Can't remember last when I'm this happy :). I can't see the "Mark as Answer" thing.